# CSS3 border and with border-radius

Tags: css

I have encounter a problem with border and border radius.

the following is result in Chrome and Firefox, Chrome render the radius very smooth however firefox is not (same as IE), i have also attached my CSS below. It's a `<a>` tag

any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
#dot{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e10000;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    text-indent: initial;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: welcome to cross-browser hell. you're witnessing the result of the lack of agreement around emerging standards

Comment: Tried using `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #EAEAEA;` also with `inset` but same sh*t.

Comment: You might not think that the Firefox implementation is perfect just yet, but I think you can assume that it will catch up in a future version. It doesn't really look that bad. How about just leaving it for now, and expecting it to look better in the future?

Comment: @DOK probably the client is a designer :D

Comment: @leemo I would now say it's a lack of *agreement*, but rather standards *implementation* used technologies and techniques are quite different, and there's lot of other bugs to fix in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

dummy border

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LChyd/)

wrap  tag with 
and use difference of width and height instead of border

```
#dot_wrapper
, #dot_inner
{
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
/*
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
*/
    text-indent: initial;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

#dot_wrapper
{
    background: #EAEAEA;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    left: 40px;
    top: 50px;
}

#dot_inner
{
    background: #e10000;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works, but i think i just going to leave that 1px solid border rather than have to do the wrapper, and hope the browser will catch up later very soon.

Answer (score 1):

All the comments are more or less correct.  The only way to achieve exactly cross-browser sameness is an image in this case.  I recently sat in on a W3C panel session at the HTML5 dev conf in SF, CA, and this exact standard (border radius) was used as an example of the incredible  complexity of standardizing even a simple feature like border radius.  (Read the spec for a kick here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius).  Essentially Roko is correct, chrome implements the feature with anti aliasing, ie/ff do not, at least with the version/settings u are using.

Good news is that for a user who has these versions/settings, this is how border radii "just look" to them, so yours won't be offensively different to their eye.

I would leave it, and fret not a moment over it.

Comment: Thanks Stolli will leave it as it is.